# Display progress bar on separate window in tcl

Tags: progress-bar, tcl, tk-toolkit

I need help in writing code for window progress bar in Tcl/tk when some of my code is running. The progress bar window may be in left or right side of the screen.

Comment: We don't write code for you, we provide advice after you provide code you have tried

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using an ancient version (and if you are, *upgrade!*) you should have a progress bar shipping with Tk. [`ttk::progressbar`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_progressbar.htm) is pretty easy to use, and supports a few patterns of use. One of the easiest is to bind it to a global variable:

```
set progress 0
pack [ttk::progressbar .p -variable progress]

# Run the progress bar from 0% to 100%, one step every 0.1s, after a 1s pause
proc updateProgress {} {
    global progress
    if {$progress < 100} {
        incr progress
        after 100 updateProgress
    }
}
after 1000 updateProgress
```

The main tricky thing is that you *must* continue to service the event loop while using the progress bar so it has a chance to update (which might be needed for the current widget theme), just as when doing anything else with Tk. If you're doing CPU-heavy work, you might need to add in calls to `update` from time to time (at least 10 times a second ideally), and that in turn requires care because you can have reentrancy issues with other parts of the GUI generating events while you're working.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions